# Trouble connecting to a PostgreSQL Database? no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.57.76", no encrpytion

Tags: postgresql

I have a computer I was just given that is hosting a PostgreSQL 14 database on it.  On my local computer I have just freshly installed PgAdmin 4.

On PgAdmin, I made a new server group named after the customer I am doing work for and then am attempting to connect to this server.  I am entering my credentials

[image]

and

[image]

But I keep getting the error as shown in the bottom of my second picture - `Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "192.168.57.60" port 5432 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.57.76", user "root", database "PostgreSQL 14", no encrpytion`

I have found other stack overflows regarding a similar message saying no SSL, and requiring changes and I do already have

`listen_addresses = '*'` in my postgresql.conf
and

```
host all all      ::1/128      scram-sha-256
host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 scram-sha-256
```

in `pg_hba.conf`.

I don't know what else to change or to fix.  What am I missing here to connect?

Comment: If that's the entire contents of `pg_hba.conf`, you're missing the entry that allows you to connect to the database from a remote host (just like the error message is telling you).

Comment: That's not the entire contents, thats just what I saw was relevant in other stack overflow posts so I wanted to let that be known it is already there.  What should I look for or add to allow remote hosts?

Comment: Also, the actual database name you want to connect to is unlikely to contain spaces, so `PostgreSQL 14` isn't right.

Comment: I checked the server name and it does in fact have a space.  I don't know if that complicates things.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess PostGreSQL 14 is what first appears under `Servers` but underneath that I do see the actual database names.  Thank you, that is one thing I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tu allow connections from the machine where pgAdmin runs. In `pg_hba.conf`, add a line like

```
host  all  username  192.168.0.0/16  scram-sha-256
```

Then reload or restart PostgreSQL (the latter is necessary if you change `listen_addresses`), and there should be an improvement.

Note that the database user is almost certainly *not* called `root`, and the database almost certainly *not* `PostgreSQL 14`. I don't know what choices you made when you setup PostgreSQL, but try `postgres` for both.